Проблема ограничения длины сообщения в Telegram
В общем, я делаю Telegram бота, где можно общаться анонимно через ссылки.
Telegram разделяет сообщение каждые 4096 символов: если пользователь отправит, допустим, сообщение длинной 16 384 символов, то Telegram отправит 4 сообщения по 4 096 символов.
По такому примеру мой обработчик сообщений будет вызван4 раза, и он отправит пользователю 4 сообщения о лимите, чего я не хочу.
Мне нужно получить эти 4 сообщения как одно единое, а потом уже обрабатывать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это реализовать?

Что реализовать? if (text.Length > 4000) { отказ; } else { отправка; }

@aepot так, а если пользователь отправит сообщение в 6000 символов, то вывод такой будет:
Максимальная длина сообщения 4000 символов
Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено

Телеграм как то даёт понять, что "вот тебе первые 4096 символов и сейчас ещё накину"?

@tym32167 не знаю, тоже хочу узнать

@tym32167, вряд ли, потому что мессенджер показывает отдельными сообщениями.
